# Websocket with Client Certificate

Tags: java, websocket

I have a Java websocket client using the javax.websocket libraries which currently looks like this:

```
WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
container.setDefaultMaxTextMessageBufferSize(BUFFER_SIZE);
container.connectToServer(this, ENDPOINT_URI);
```

Now I have the requirement, that the client needs to supply a client certificate to the server. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution, so I answer my own question:

The WebsocketContainer can be configured with an ClientEndpointConfig. This allows to set a custom SSLContext. Then client certificate must be attached to the SSLContext. Code:

```
WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
container.setDefaultMaxTextMessageBufferSize(BUFFER_SIZE);
container.connectToServer(new PojoEndpointClient(this, new ArrayList<>()), createClientConfig(), endpointURI);
```

And the ClientEndpointConfig can be constructed like this:

```
private ClientEndpointConfig createClientConfig() throws KeyManagementException, UnrecoverableKeyException,
 NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, CertificateException, IOException {
    ClientEndpointConfig.Builder builder = ClientEndpointConfig.Builder.create();
    ClientEndpointConfig config = builder.decoders(new ArrayList<>()).encoders(new ArrayList<>())
            .preferredSubprotocols(new ArrayList<>()).build();
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().loadKeyMaterial(clientCert.toFile(), clientCertPassword,
            clientCertPassword, (aliases, socket) -> aliases.keySet().iterator().next()).build();
    config.getUserProperties().put(Constants.SSL_CONTEXT_PROPERTY, sslContext);
    return config;
}
```

This will present the client certificate to the server when establishing the websocket connection.

Comment: Constants.SSL_CONTEXT_PROPERTY is missing when the method is implemented. What library did you use?

Comment: Its from Apache Tomcat: org.apache.tomcat.websocket.Constants

Comment: Note that `SSLContexts.custom()` doesn't exist in recent versions, instead use `org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContextBuilder` from `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore`:

```java
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContextBuilder
            .create()
            .loadKeyMaterial(new File(p12File), p12Password, p12Password)
            .build();
        clientConfig.getUserProperties().put(Constants.SSL_CONTEXT_PROPERTY, sslContext);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what certificate you are talking about, but probably you mean [SSL/TLS](https://www.thesslstore.com/new-to-ssl/what-is-ssl-tls.aspx) certificate. In this case you need just to use **wss** client(eg [nv-websocket-client](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client)), which will handle all ssl/tls under the hood.

See also answer: [minimal java8 nio secure websocket client (wss)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30069530/3014866)

Comment: SSL/TLS is not the issue. We already connect using wss. But additionaly, I need to provide a client certificate.